# Change multiple properties of a JIRA issue w/ single click

Tags: jira

About 1/2 of my sprint consists of unplanned issues and I'd like to streamline working with foreign and new tickets. They should appear on my Kanban but the board is set to display only issues in my project.

How do I integrate a button that automates some or all of these steps:

- Put the ticket in my current sprint
- If its not in the project of my current sprint move it there (don't show up dialogue, assume some defaults)
- Instead of a button do all this when the ticket is assigned to me

I suppose the last step can be done by exploiting post-functions. For the rest I have no clue.

Comment: What did Atlassian support say?

Comment: They sort-of responded: `You can implement an issue listener that does all that automatically. You can use Script Runner or JJUpin to write the listener`. That kind of gives the general direction but some example or best-practice to start with would definitely straighten the path for me.